# How we pass the headers inside swagger rspecs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-token-auth, rswag

I'm getting this error when I run the rspec
**Response body: {"success":false,"errors":["Invalid login credentials"]}**
here is my code

```
path '/api/auth/validate_token' do
  get 'check token' do
    tags 'TokenValidations'
    consumes 'application/json'
    security [client: {}, uid: {}, access_token:  {}]
    response '200', 'success' do
      let(:headers) { user.create_new_auth_token }
      run_test!
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same problem and tried to execute below, then worked for me.

```
let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user, password: 'password') }
let(:tokens) do
  post "/api/v1/authority/sign_in",
       params: { email: user[:email], password: 'password' },
       as: :json
  response.headers.slice('client', 'access-token', 'uid')
end

path '/api/v1/messages/' do
    get 'Retrieves some messages' do
        description 'Get some messages from provided data'
        produces 'application/json'
        parameter name: 'access-token', in: :header, type: :string
        parameter name: 'client', in: :header, type: :string
        parameter name: 'uid', in: :header, type: :string
        response '200', 'messages found' do
            let(:client) { tokens['client'] }
            let('access-token') { tokens['access-token'] }
            let(:uid) { tokens['uid'] }
            schema '$ref' => '#/components/schemas/messages'
            run_test!
        end
    end
end
```